# How does the Twitter app count impressions?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, twitter, tableview

So, for every tweet, Twitter will count its impressions, that is, on how many screens it has appeared. No interaction is required to count an impression, the tweet just has to be shown.

If the Twitter feed is a `UITableView` and every tweet is a `UITableViewCell`, how can this be achieved?

Initially, I tried to add an impression in the `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)` method like so:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TweetCell", for: indexPath) as! TweetCell
    let tweet = feed[indexPath.row]

    cell.configure(with: tweet)
    addImpression(for: tweet) // adding impression here...

    return cell
}
```

But this method might be called many times for every cell as the user scrolls past or as the `UITableView` reloads, which would cause several impressions to be added instead of just one.

I suppose what might make this work is a code block that only runs once per cell. Is there such a thing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have your tweet struct (with a hasSeen bool value) like below:

```
struct Tweet {
  var user: String
  var text: String
  var hasSeen: Bool
  var date: Date
  // and etc.
}
```

Then modify your `cellForRowAt` method like below:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "TweetCell", for: indexPath) as! TweetCell
  let tweet = feed[indexPath.row]

  if tweet.hasSeen == false {
    addImpression(for: tweet)
    tweet.hasSeen = true
  }

  cell.configure(with: tweet)

  return cell
}
```

For each tweet you check if the tweet was displayed before or not. If it was not displayed, you add an impression, if it was, you don't.

This is an approach that I would like to try. Let me know if this works out for you.